# Empty attribute in post message in openapi

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I am creating documentation for our API. The problem is that I dont know, how to make attribute "empty" (not visible at all).

There is nice [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query-parameters). And also one same question, but it was not answered because of inactivity of user. And documentation does not helped me.

I tried:

allowEmptyValue: true

at the level of object. But the message still contains example value. Of course, I tried also delete this value. Does not help.

Attribute definiton openapi 3.0.2:

```
LanguagePrefCode:
   type: string
   allowEmptyValue: true
   example: en
   description: Language preference code.
   xml:
      attribute: true
```

Message AS IS:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request Code="Secret">
    <Context Currency: "EUR" LanguagePrefCode="en">
    </Context>
</Request>
```

Message TO BE:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request Code="Secret">
    <Context Currency: "EUR">
    </Context>
</Request>
```

Also I tried:

required: false

But it should not be at the level of object definition. Context  object has only one required attribute, which is currency. Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you mean that `Content` MAY have an optional `LanguagePrefCode` attribute, but you want to hide this attribute from the examples in Swagger UI? Or that `Content` never has the `LanguagePrefCode` attribute?

Comment: Context MAY have an optional LanguagePrefCode attribute and I would like to to hide it from the examples in Swagger UI.